# Cannot set gradle path in Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, gradle, macos-big-sur

Everytime I type gradle -v in my mac terminal it says
zsh: command not found: gradle

I need to execute : export PATH=$HOME:/Users/akarshitjoshi/downloads/gradle-4.10/bin:$PATH
everytime to get gradle running in my terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just add the export command to your ~/.zshrc file.

Comment: I used sdkman to install the gradle and it worked fine